# OpenSSL cannot connect to free.currencyconverterapi.com

Tags: windows, openssl, winsock

Recently I've migrated my program to OpenSSL due to multiple problems with built-in SSL support in the older versions of Windows. Everything works perfectly despite the site specified in the title, I constantly get error:00000001:lib(0):func(0):reason(1).

If I uncomment lines that set non-blocking mode for a socket, I just get another error message. Any help is desperately appreciated. I tested that issue using OpenSSL 1.1.1j under Windows 10 64-bits (but it seems not to be dependent on the OS version)

I thought that the problem may be caused by missing certificates, so I added Microsoft.pem to the context - nothing changed (you can grab this file from https://github.com/drwetter/testssl.sh/blob/3.1dev/etc/Microsoft.pem

That is the code that emulates my program:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>

#define HOST "free.currencyconverterapi.com"

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsadata;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsadata);

    SSL_library_init();
    SSL_load_error_strings();

    const SSL_METHOD *meth = TLS_client_method();
    if (!meth) {
        fprintf(stderr, "SSL setup failure: client method");
        return 1;
    }

    SSL_CTX *g_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(meth);
    if (!g_ctx) {
        fprintf(stderr, "SSL setup failure: context");
        return 2;
    }

    SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(g_ctx, "microsoft.pem", NULL);
    SSL_CTX_ctrl(g_ctx, SSL_CTRL_MODE, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY, nullptr);

    RAND_screen();

    addrinfo *air = nullptr, hints = { 0 };
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    if (GetAddrInfoA(HOST, "443", &hints, &air)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "AddrInfo for host %s failed (%u)", HOST, WSAGetLastError());
        return 3;
    }

   int rc = 1;
    SOCKET s = INVALID_SOCKET;

    for (auto *ai = air; ai; ai = ai->ai_next) {
        s = socket(ai->ai_family, ai->ai_socktype, ai->ai_protocol);
        if (s == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            FreeAddrInfoA(air);
            return 4;
        }

        if (connect(s, ai->ai_addr, (int)ai->ai_addrlen) == 0) {
            rc = 0;
            break;
        }

        if (WSAGetLastError() != WSAEWOULDBLOCK) {
            rc = WSAGetLastError();
            closesocket(s);
            s = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }

    }

    if (rc) {
        fprintf(stderr, "connection failed: %d", rc);
        return 6;
    }

    FreeAddrInfoA(air);

    // uncomment that lines to obtain another error code
   // u_long notblocking = 0;
    // if (ioctlsocket(s, FIONBIO, &notblocking) != 0) {
    //  FreeAddrInfoA(air);
    //  return 5;
    // }

    SSL *session = SSL_new(g_ctx);
    if (!session) {
        fprintf(stderr, "SSL setup failure: session");
        return 7;
    }

    SSL_set_fd(session, s);

    int err = SSL_connect(session);
    if (err != 1) {
        err = SSL_get_error(session, err);

        char buf[100];
        ERR_error_string_n(err, buf, sizeof(buf));
        fprintf(stderr, "SSL negotiation failure: %s (%d)", buf, err);
        return 8;
   }

    fprintf(stderr, "Connection succeeded");
   return 0;
}
```

--
WMBR, George Hazan

Comment: What value does `SSL_connect()` and `SSL_get_error()` return?

Comment: error:00000001:lib(0):func(0):reason(1)

Comment: Not an expert on OpenSSL by any means. Looking at a wireshark capture, this code ends up sending a TLS 1.0 ClientHello which the server fails. It seems like the server only supports TLS 1.3, and adding a call to `SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(session, HOST);` before the `SSL_connect()` seems to do the job.

Comment: @Luke thanks, man, it works now, glory, glory, halleluya :)